# Random vector $(X,Y)$ X and Y expectation value and standard deviation individually.

Tags: probability

$(X,Y)$ joint probability is defined with 3 probabilities.
$$P(X=-8,Y=-2)=0.2 \\ P(X=6,Y=7)=0.3 \\ P(X=-7,Y=-2)=0.5$$
I would like to find out $E[X]=\mu_y$ and $E[Y]=\mu_x$ also standard deviation for both. Standard deviation would be

$$\sigma_x = \sqrt{E[(X-\mu)^2]}=\sqrt{E[X^2]-(E[X])^2}$$
$$\sigma_y = \sqrt{E[(Y-\mu)^2]}=\sqrt{E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2}$$

Now the problem is that i dont know how do you get expected value for $X$ and $Y$ individually from joint probability. However i am familiar with calculating expected value for single random variable. Hint in right direction would be great, mayby there is formula for this ?

Comment: Standard deviation would be: $$\sigma_x = \sqrt{\sum_{x,y} [x^2 P(X=x,Y=y)]-(\sum_{x,y}[xP(X=x,Y=y)^2}]$$ $$\sigma_Y = \sqrt{\sum_{x,y} [y^2 P(X=x,Y=y)]-(\sum_{x,y}[yP(X=x,Y=y)^2}]$$

Comment: Regarding putting the sums in for both $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ in here, see my comment on my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the law of total expectation (there are varying names for this):
$$
E(X) = \sum_x x P(X = x) = \sum_{x,y} x P(X = x, Y = y).
$$
From this, you can input the values of $x$ and $y$, and do the sum.

---

For finding the variance (and hence standard deviation), try to think of how you can write it as a sum like I have. You've already got them in a nice form to work with. :)

Comment: As a reminder, once you've calculated $E(X)$ using the above formula, you can use $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$, and so you need only calculate $E(X^2)$ -- which you can do using a very similar method to what I've done above.

Answer (score 0):

In general if $X,Y$ have a joint discrete distribution and $f$ is a function then: $$\mathbb Ef(X,Y)=\sum_x\sum_y f(x,y)P(X=x\wedge Y=y)$$

To find e.g. $\mathbb EX$ you can apply that on function $f$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x$

To find e.g. $\mathbb EY^2$ you can apply that on function $f$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto y^2$

Comment: What does $\wedge$ mean in this notation ?

Comment: It is a notation for "and".

Answer (score 0):

I add here calculated values for these which are correct.

$$\mu_x = -3.3$$
$$\mu_y = 0.7$$
$$E(X^2)=48.1$$
$$E(Y^2)=17.5$$
$$\sigma_x=6.1$$
$$\sigma_y=4.12$$