# Random vector $(X,Y)$ correlation and $E(XY)$

Tags: probability

Previously discussed things that are related to this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455733/random-vector-x-y-x-and-y-expectation-value-and-standard-deviation-individua)

$(X,Y)$ joint probability is defined with 3 probabilities.
$$P(X=-8,Y=-2)=0.2 \\ P(X=6,Y=7)=0.3 \\ P(X=-7,Y=-2)=0.5$$

Now i would like to know expected value for $E(XY)$. This is suppose to be same thing as: ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)) $$ E(XY) = E(X)E(Y) $$
But for some unknown reason i dont seem to get correct answer with this. ? (my quess is that we cannot use this formula because in this we assume that $x,y$ are independent and in this case we dont know for certain if it is or not.) Values i used to calculate this are here:

$$\mu_x = -3.3$$
$$\mu_y = 0.7$$
$$E(X^2)=48.1$$
$$E(Y^2)=17.5$$
$$\sigma_x=6.1$$
$$\sigma_y=4.12$$

These are calculeted in post which i linked  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455733/random-vector-x-y-x-and-y-expectation-value-and-standard-deviation-individua)

Also correlation for $x,y$ would be:

$$\rho x,y= \frac{E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)}{\sqrt{E(X^2)-E^2(X)}\sqrt{E(Y^2)-E^2(Y)}}$$
$$\rho x,y= \frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y}$$

In order to calculate (Pearsson's) correlation we need to know $E(XY)$ so how do we calculate $E(XY)$ if we cannot say if $X,Y$ are dependent of each other or not ?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, which is why the formula $E[XY]= E[X] E[Y]$ does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X=-8,Y=-2)=0.2 \\ P(X=6,Y=7)=0.3 \\ P(X=-7,Y=-2)=0.5$$

implies

$$P(XY=16)=0.2 \\ P(XY=42)=0.3 \\ P(X=14)=0.5$$

and so

$$E[XY] = 0.2 \times 16 +0.3\times 42 +.5\times 14 =22.8$$
$$E[XY] - E[X]\, E[Y] = 22.8-(-3.3)\times 0.7 = 25.11$$

Comment: In fact it seems $\rho_{x,y}^{\,} \approx 0.998$ so they are a long way from being independent